# not a group group function in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table (invoice) like

```
InovoiceID     Invoice amount
```

I want to select the invoicenumber, the average invoiceamount, and the difference between actual amount and average invoiceamount for each row. However, when I try to do this,

```
select invoiceID, 
       avg(invoiceamount) as Average, 
       Average - invoiceamount
  from invoice
```

This shows an error that sql command is not complete.

Why is this happening?

PS: I even tried this,

```
SELECT invoiceid, 
       (SELECT AVG(invoiceamount) FROM Invoice) AS avg_invamt, 
       (SELECT AVG(invoiceamount) FROM Invoice) - invoiceamount AS diff 
  FROM Invoice
```

But still it shows error.
I am using oracle database express edition.

Comment: then you should change your tag to oracle, not mysql.

Comment: I did that and someone edited it and removed oracle. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wan't to do without is giving the `group group` error because you are using a group function without specifing a `group by` statement. So you can achieve what you want with a sub query or even with the `with` clause.

In my examples I change a bit the names of the columns.

```
with a as (
    select avg(amount) average
      from invoice
    )
select id, a.average, a.average - amount as diff
  from invoice, a;
```

OR

```
select id, a.average, a.average - amount as diff
  from invoice, 
       (select avg(amount) average
          from invoice) a;
```

See it here on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c33e/8

Comment: Why is there a `a` at the end of the select query `(select avg(amount) average
          from invoice) a;` in the second solution?

Comment: It is an ALIAS. just to nickname the subquery that way i can use the column as `a.average`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a query that would benefit windowing functions
However, MySQL doesn't support these kinds of functions.The query below should work.

```
SELECT invoiceId, avg_inv.amt AS "Average", 
avg_inv.amt - invoice.invoiceamount AS "Difference"
FROM invoice, 
(SELECT avg(invoiceamount) as "amt" FROM invoice) avg_inv
```

#### update: just noticed the question tag changed from mysql to oracle. now you can use windowing functions.

[heres a description of their usage in oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html), or you can search the countless SO questions regarding windowing functions.

Comment: Why is there `avg_inv` at the end of the select query after the from statement?

Comment: the avg_invoice is the alias for the expression (select avg(invoiceamount) as 'amt' from invoice). I got lazy and did not put the "AS" keyword which is optional